# How do I make elements flow horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: php, css, xhtml

I have a link after an image in my xhtml.  The browser automatically puts a return character after the image so that the link is below the image.  I want the link to be beside the image.  How do I modify the CSS/XHTML for this?

PHP generates it like this(example code)

```
  echo "<img class = \"c\" src=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/favicon.ico\" alt=\"\"\/>";
  echo "<a name = \"a1\" class = \"b\" href = \"$ass_array[url]\">$ass_array[name]</a>";
```

CSS

```
img.c
  {
  display:??;
  }

a.b
  {
  color:#000088;
  padding-top:2px;
  padding-bottom:2px; 
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
  }
```

Comment: I wish you'd have included all that code at the start. First there was no code, then just HTML, and then along came the CSS..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/vgnAa/

**CSS:**

```
.c {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
.b {
    color:#000088;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-bottom:2px; 
    display:block;
    border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either float: left, float: right depending which side you want the link to be. Apply that to both, and make sure to have a clear div after.

This way you can still have that display:block on .b.

Answer (score 0):

"float:left;" for both elements will work